# Display Random Text on button click

Tags: android, button, textview

I would like to have a button and when you click the button it displays a phrase at random.
I've done a little research and (I have a limited knowledge of java) i believe i would have to use an array and it display a random string of text.
can someone tell me what code i'd have to use?

Comment: You can use the Java Random() class to generate random numbers.  I would suggest Googling this.  You will find 9^9^9 tutorials online.

Comment: Show us some sample code of what you've tried, and tell us what isn't working about it.

Comment: dude share teh code first :) then the ppl will here help you out. :)

Answer (score 1):

The Android API example [TextToSpeechActivity](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/TextToSpeechActivity.html) does exactly what you want.

Here's the relevant snippet of code:

```
private static final Random RANDOM = new Random();

private static final String[] HELLOS = {
  "Hello",
  "Salutations",
  "Greetings",
  "Howdy",
  "What's crack-a-lackin?",
  "That explains the stench!"
};

private void sayHello() {
    // Select a random hello.
    int helloLength = HELLOS.length;
    String hello = HELLOS[RANDOM.nextInt(helloLength)];
}
```